# Android CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE boxes not showing

Tags: android, list

I have the following code returning a list from a database. I want to use a checkbox list so people can do a search on beaches with certain facilities, but I can’t get it to show the check boxes, it just displays a normal list!

```
public class FacilitySearch extends ListActivity  {

    private DatabaseHelper dbBookHelper = null;
    private Cursor ourCursor = null;
    private BookAdapter adapter = null;
    public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.fnesse.beachguide._ID";

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        ListView myListView = getListView();
        myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

        dbBookHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbBookHelper.createDatabase();       
        ourCursor = dbBookHelper.getFacilities(); 
        startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
        adapter=new BookAdapter(ourCursor);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {       
            Intent i = new Intent(FacilitySearch.this, Administration.class);
            i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    class BookAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        BookAdapter(Cursor c) {
          super(FacilitySearch.this, c);
        }
        @Override
        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
            BookHolder holder = (BookHolder)row.getTag();
            holder.populateFrom(c, dbBookHelper);
        }
        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
          LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
          View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);
          BookHolder holder=new BookHolder(row);
          row.setTag(holder);
          return(row);
        }
      }

    static class BookHolder {
        private TextView name = null;

        BookHolder(View row) {
            name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.beachListText);
        }

        void populateFrom(Cursor c, DatabaseHelper r) {
            name.setText(r.getName(c));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include in your list item a CheckedTextView with

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

as shown in the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice [resource](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml).

It's the same when you extend ListActivity and you define your own main layout you need to have a ListView with id

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

Comment: I tried that first then I found this example at android and I don’t need a layout at all: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List11.html plus I found somewhere else someone saying “remove setContentView(R.layout.thelists);, you only need it if you are doing something radicle“

Comment: Did you try to add the CheckedTextView to R.layout.row2?